# Definition of a measurable function

Tags: measure-theory

$f\colon \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is said to be measurable if for all $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, $\{x \mid f(x)>\alpha\}\in F$ (i.e., $f^{−1}(\alpha,+\infty)\in F$)
where $\Omega$ is the sample space and $F$ is the $\sigma$-algebra.
Also there is a statement that says "every subset of $\sigma$-algebra is measurable". 
I still have problems with understanding these definitons. Can you explain the definition in a very simple way?

Comment: I don't understand the second sentence with subsets of $\sigma$-algebra, but for the first, it simply says that "The measure of $\{x: F(x)\in I\}$" where $I$ is an interval, is well-defined. In probability, the sentence "Probability that the random variable will take values in the interval $I$" makes sense.

Comment: Every *element* (not subset) of the $\sigma$-algebra is by definition a measurable set. Next to measurable sets there are also measurable functions. A function $f$ is measurable if the preimages of measurable sets under $f$ are measurable. Compare it with: a function $g$ is continuous if preimages of open sets under $g$ are open.

Comment: @drhab Isn't a function measurable if the preimage of *Borel* sets are measurable?

Comment: @PeterFranek Mostly you are indeed dealing with that case. But in a more general setting with two measurable spaces $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$ and $(\Omega',\mathcal A')$ a function $f:\Omega\rightarrow\Omega'$ with the mentioned characteristics is also labeled as 'measurable'.